# How do I automatically start a service on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, service, ubuntu-15.10

I need to run postgresql for my Rails app, which I do like this at the terminal:

```
$ sudo service postgresql start
```

How do I automate this process so that postgresql just starts automatically for me either whenever my app needs it, whenever I login, or whenever my server starts.  I'm on Ubuntu 15.10.

Thanks.

Comment: You should edit your question, this is terribly worded. It's got nothing to do with the actual error you've posted, you're really asking how to automate that `sudo service postgresql start` command, presumably in some Linux distro, and really that question belongs on SuperUser.com

Comment: @smathy : sure I agree with you, my question have two contest, Ss there anyway to stop this error from happening ? If not, and I have to run this command manually right,So the second question is,  then what is the method to automate that process.

Comment: @allhatersofSO Hey guys who is flagging this post without further reading the post, common, you are most welcome. Thanks for your kind support.

Comment: There you go Praveen, I didn't like the haters either so I fixed your question so that it contains only the relevant information for your actual problem. I'll remove my -1 now, but I'll leave my recommendation to close this because it actually belongs in SuperUser.

Comment: @smathy: thanks for the support shown bro :)

Answer (score 2):

Auto start PostgreSQL on OS startup.

I'm not sure about, which OS you're using. On Ubuntu it should be:

```
sudo update-rc.d postgresql enable
```

There are several ways to auto start a program per OS. Better consult to your specific OS docs.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 15.10 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Stale PID needs removal.
First step

> rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid

Second step

> pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres   -l
>   /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start

Comment: Thanks for your time, could you please explain what these  commands do, and what is the effect of these commands in our system ?

Comment: The first one removes a pid file. It needs to be removed as your system probably shut down while your Postgres connection was still on. The second one restarts the Postgres server. I'm not an expert but found this solution on this forum and it works for me.

Comment: Whenever you get this error. I think if you shut down your local server in the proper way before shutting your Mac you shouldn't be getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly the procedures you used to install postgres , but when I installed Ubuntu 10.15 had permission issues that prevented the service from starting.

1 ) try to start:

```
service postgresql start
```

2 ) make sure that Postgres is the list of services:

```
ps -ef
```

3 ) If not, check the log:

```
cat /var/log/syslog
```

4 ) At this point my problem was allowed access to the ssl key. If your case also, do:

```
chown postgres. /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

5 ) try to start again:

```
service postgresql start
```

With this my Postgres started normally (forever)